# How to make that work service with g_bus_own_name?

Tags: c, linux, dbus

I write code. I writing on C programming with gio. It start on server and print error. stackoverflow requires more words, but nothing to write.

```
static void set_server_dbus ( void ) {
    unsigned int owner_id;
    introspection_data = g_dbus_node_info_new_for_xml (introspection_xml, NULL);

    owner_id = g_bus_own_name ( G_BUS_TYPE_SESSION,
            "com.xverizex.trade_bot",
            G_BUS_NAME_OWNER_FLAGS_NONE,
            on_bus_acquired,
            on_name_acquired,
            on_name_lost,
            NULL,
            NULL );
}
...
int main ( int argc, char **argv ) {
    init_buffers ( );
    mysql = mysql_init ( NULL );
    if ( mysql_real_connect ( mysql, "localhost", "gag", "gag", "binance", 0, NULL, 0 ) == NULL ) {
        printf ( "не правильные данные для базы данных.\n" );
        return -1;
    }

    set_server_dbus ( );
    subscribe_to_net_device ( );

    if ( power_net == 100 ) {
        connect_to_network ( );
        printf ( "!ok\n" );
    }

    GMainLoop *loop;
    loop = g_main_loop_new ( NULL, FALSE );
    g_main_loop_run ( loop );
    return 0;
}
```

If start in terminal, then is ok, but if start via systemctl, then print error.

```
server@server:~$ systemctl status trade_bot.service 
● trade_bot.service - trade bot
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/trade_bot.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-10-12 23:22:32 UTC; 4min 49s ago
    Process: 1511 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/trade_bot (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 1511 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 12 23:22:32 server systemd[1]: Started trade bot.
Oct 12 23:22:32 server trade_bot[1511]: SUCCEED: Подключение к сетевому интерфейсу успешно.
Oct 12 23:22:32 server trade_bot[1511]: SUCCEED: Получение сетевого интерфейса успешно.
Oct 12 23:22:32 server trade_bot[1511]: SUCCEED: Успешное подключение к NetworkManager.Device.
Oct 12 23:22:32 server trade_bot[1511]: !ok
Oct 12 23:22:32 server systemd[1]: trade_bot.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 12 23:22:32 server systemd[1]: trade_bot.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

This is service_file.

```
[Unit]
Description=trade bot
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/trade_bot

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

it call this.

```
static void
on_name_lost (GDBusConnection *connection,
              const gchar     *name,
              gpointer         user_data)
{
  exit (1);
}
```

but why?
This is introspection_xml.as you can see, here the interface has a full path.

```
static const gchar introspection_xml[] =
  "<node>"
  "  <interface name='com.xverizex.trade_bot.status'>"
  "    <method name='stop_trading'>"
  "      <arg type='u' name='status' direction='out'/>"
  "    </method>"
  "    <method name='start_trading'>"
  "      <arg type='u' name='status' direction='out'/>"
  "    </method>"
  "  <property type='u' name='is_connected' access='read'/>"
  "  <signal name='connection_changed'>"
  "    <arg type='u' name='status'/>"
  "  </signal>"
  "  </interface>"
  "</node>";
```

Comment: `introspection_xml` is the full absolute path? Does the process has the correct credentials (files or group)?

Comment: @Robert I added introspection_xml.